# Wildcard for parameter in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, wildcard, viewmodel

I have at least four different classes for some viewmodels that I want to use to generate partial views. The thing is that each of those partial views generates a dropdown in the exact same way.

```
public class LocalityGeneratorForm
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description of the field")]
    public Locality[] locality { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Locality> Localities { get; }
}

public class GoalGeneratorForm
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "A different description of the field")]
    public Goal[] goal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Goal> Goals { get; }
}

public class ProcessGeneratorForm
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "A third description of the field")]
    public Process[] process { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Process> Processes { get; }
}

public class FieldGeneratorForm
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "The other new description of the field")]
    public Field[] field { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get;  }
}
```

Ok, so all this ViewModels are really similar, they only differ in the type of the ICollection. Now, to generate the HTML string, I will use a function that will take two parameters, being one, the name of the partial view that will serve as a template and the other one, the model.

So I want to be able to create that method willing to accept an instance of any of the classes above or in the future, maybe more.

```
private string ConvertViewToString( string viewName, <GenericClass> model ) 
{
    //-- Do stuff..
    return "My HTML";
}
```

The first question is, is it possible and if so, how do I declare the generic parameter? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Generic method, you can simply do:

```cs
private string ConvertViewToString<T>(string viewName, T model) {
    //-- Do stuff..
    return "My HTML";
}

// How to call this method?
LocalityGeneratorForm localGenForm = new LocalityGeneratorForm(); /* Simple instancing */

// in this case, T will automatically LocalityGeneratorForm.
ConvertViewToString(some_string, localGenForm);

// or you can explicit define what T type is
ConvertViewToString<LocalityGeneratorForm>(some_string, localGenForm);
```

and If you want to restrict the type of type parameter `T`, you can use `where`.

If you really want to make restriction that `ConvertViewToString` method will take `SomethingTopModelClass` and it's derived types only, you can use like this:

```cs
private string ConvertViewToString<T>(string viewName, T model) where T: SomethingTopModelClass {
    //-- Do stuff..
    return "My HTML";
}
```

My explanation may hard to understand (bad English :S), so I recommend you to read about documents below.

[C# Generics (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

[C# Generics - Where (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: Tried your answer and worked perfectly, I am also tempted to try Anag's approach, I was wondering if there is a difference in performance between the two? The system I am building is for a government facility and they eat a lot of resources.

Comment: @Tales Well actually it does not related with performance closely. It matters about maintenance. Anag's approach will gives you better maintenance since it uses an interface to group up classes(in this context, `XXXGeneratorForm`)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is not a generic method/class. The best way to achieve this is by modifying the `ConvertViewToString` to accept an interface rather than a specific implementation. Injecting interface to a method will have much more flexibility in the future.

```
public interface IHtmlElement {
    string ToHtmlString();
}

public class LocalityGeneratorForm : IHtmlElement
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description of the field")]
    public Locality[] locality { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Locality> Localities { get; }
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        // convert Locality to html string representation
        return "<p>HTML element string for Locality</p>"
    }
}

public class GoalGeneratorForm : IHtmlElement
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "A different description of the field")]
    public Goal[] goal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Goal> Goals { get; }
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        // convert Goal to html string representation
        return "<p>HTML element string for Goal</p>"
    }
}
```

In the next step, you can do the `ConverViewToString` implementation this way:

```
private string ConvertViewToString( string viewName, IHtmlElement element ) 
{
    //-- Do stuff..
    return element.ToHtmlString();
}
```

This is how you can put everything together:

```
var locality = new LocalityGeneratorForm();
var goal = new GoalGeneratorForm();

var htmlLocality = ConvertViewToString("some name", locality);
var htmlGoal = ConvertViewToString("some name", goal);
```

Hopefully, my answer can help you make your implementation more flexible.